# Prism. Closing a dialog created with IDialogService

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, prism

I am trying to use a new IDialogService which was discussed in github issue [1666. A New IDialogService for WPF](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/issues/1666). I like this new feature but I can't find a solution for one case of using IDialogService in compare with InteractionRequest.

There is a button, pressing on which non-modal dialog is opened. If user press the same button one more time, while dialog still open, dialog close. How this behavior should be implemented in a proper way?

**MainWindowViewModel**

```cs
public class MainWindowViewModel : BindableBase
{
    private readonly IDialogService _dialogService;
    public DelegateCommand CustomPopupCommand { get; }

    public MainWindowViewModel(IDialogService dialogService)
    {
        _dialogService = dialogService;
        CustomPopupCommand = new DelegateCommand(OpenClosePopup);
    }

    private void OpenClosePopup()
    {
        // It looks like some additional logic should be implemented here.
        // How to save previously opened IDialogAware instance and close it if needed?
        _dialogService.Show("CustomPopupView", new DialogParameters("Title=Good Title"), result => { });
    }
}
```

**CustomPopupViewModel**

```cs
public class CustomPopupViewModel : BindableBase, IDialogAware
{
    private string _title;
    public string Title
    {
        get => _title;
        set => SetProperty(ref _title, value);
    }
    public DelegateCommand<object> CloseCommand { get; }

    public CustomPopupViewModel()
    {
        CloseCommand = new DelegateCommand<object>(CloseDialog);
    }

    public event Action<IDialogResult> RequestClose;

    public void OnDialogOpened(IDialogParameters parameters)
    {
        Title = parameters.GetValue<string>(nameof(Title));
    }

    public void OnDialogClosed()
    {
    }

    public bool CanCloseDialog()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public void RaiseRequestClose(IDialogResult dialogResult)
    {
        RequestClose?.Invoke(dialogResult);
    }

    private void CloseDialog(object button)
    {
        RaiseRequestClose(
            new DialogResult(button is ButtonResult buttonResult ? buttonResult : ButtonResult.Cancel));
    }
}
```

I have no idea how can it be implemented in proper way because method IDialogService.Show() fully decoupled from knowing about ViewModel and View. Of course except the name of View.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can always send an event through the event aggregator, probably you have to pass some id in the dialog parameters to close the right dialog if there's more than one open at a time.

But this feels really clunky, I'd prefer to get an `IDisposable` from `Show`/`ShowDialog` that closes the dialog on `Dispose`.

```
public CustomPopupViewModel(IEventAggregator eventAggregator)
{
    eventAggregator.GetEvent<CloseDialogEvent>().Subscribe( id => { if (id == _id) CloseMe(); } );
}

public void OnDialogOpened(IDialogParameters parameters)
{
    _id = parameters.GetValue<string>("id");
}

_dialogService.Show("CustomPopupView", new DialogParameters("id=12345"), result => { });

_eventAggregator.GetEvent<CloseDialogEvent>().Publish("12345");
```

Comment: Hm.. it can be a solution but as you mentioned a bit clunky. I'm thinking about using approach like in MVVMDialogs, where you can pass ViewModel to the dialog service and the dialog service set ViewModel as DataContext of View, instead of using auto-wiring like in Prism

Comment: @YarikM yes, a view model-first dialog service would be a good solution, too.

Comment: I am facing the same issue, is this the best solution to close an already open prism dialogservice from the caller viewmodel? Surprising that there isn't much information on this anywhere.

Comment: I've created an issue at github. Can you add your use cases to the `Intened Use Case` section? https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/issues/2007

Comment: I tried this and after the dialog launches it doesn't even get to the last line of your code. It's still waiting for the dialog result

Comment: @baydbest do you call `Show` or `ShowDialog`? The latter I'd expect to wait (you could still raise the event from another thread), but `Show` shouldn't block.

Answer (score 0):

I find it simplest to use Prism implementation of the subscriber pattern
I use a class that will be used in the pattern and is communicated:

```
public class DialogStatus
{ 
    public bool DialogResult { get; set; }
}
```

In my sample, I show you how I do this using a Login Dialog in WPF using Prism 8.0.0.1909

**in the App.cs**

```
protected override void OnInitialized()
{
   var login = Container.Resolve<LoginDialog>();
   var result = login.ShowDialog();
   if (result.HasValue && result.Value)
   {
       base.OnInitialized();
   }
   else
   {
      Application.Current.Shutdown();
   }
}
```

**in LoginDialog.cs** in my **Dialogs** folder

```
public partial class LoginDialog : Window
{
    public LoginDialog(IEventAggregator eventAggregator)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        eventAggregator.GetEvent<CloseDialogWindowEvent>().Subscribe(OnCloseWindow);
    }

    private void OnCloseWindow(DialogStatus obj)
    {
        base.DialogResult = obj.DialogResult;
    }
}
```

now anywhere in my code, in a ViewModel of view a custom control's view model, the only thing I need to do is pass the IEventAggregator in in the constructor and save it in a field.

```
private readonly IEventAggregator _eventAggregator;
public LoginControlViewModel(IAuthenticationService authenticationService
                            , IConnectFileImporterService connectFileImporterService
                            , IDialogService dialogService
                            , IEventAggregator eventAggregator)
{

   _eventAggregator= eventAggregator;
   // the other code
}
```

I can now close my dialog, and in this sample return true to falls to my OnInitalize in  my App.cs from anywhere by calling

```
_eventAggregator.GetEvent<CloseDialogWindowEvent>().Publish(new CloseDialogWindowEvent() { DialogResult = true });
```

or

```
_eventAggregator.GetEvent<CloseDialogWindowEvent>().Publish(new CloseDialogWindowEvent() { DialogResult = false});
```

Answer (score 0):

If i understand correctly, you want to close the dailog window programmatically instead of clicking the windows's close button, right? If It is true,  maybe I can provide you with a solution. Although this method is not very elegant, it is very simple.

My project use mahapps styles, I want use metrowindow as the dailoghost window. Following prism documentation, I register dialoghost window and usercontrol like this:

```
containerRegistry.RegisterDialogWindow<DialogHost>(nameof(DialogHost));
containerRegistry.RegisterDialog<UserEdit, UserEditViewModel>(nameof(UserEdit));
```

The UserEidt is a usercontrol, I place a confirm button and a cancel button in UserEidt, and both button binding DelegateCommand in UserEditViewModel. The question is, how can i close dailogwindow by clicking the cancel button?

Here is my solution, firstly define a IDailogViewModel interface:

```
public interface IDialogViewModel
{
    Action CloseDialogWindow { get; set; }
}
```

Then UserEditViewModel implement this interface:

```
public class UserEditViewModel : BindableBase, IDialogAware,IDialogViewModel
{
   public DelegateCommand CancelCmd { get; private set; }
   public Action CloseDialogWindow { get; set; }
   
   public UserEditViewModel()
   {
       CancelCmd = new DelegateCommand(CloseDialogWindow)
   }

   private void CloseDialogWindow()
   {
       CloseDialogWindow.Invoke();
   }
}
```

Infact, when the dialog window popup, the UserEdit will be dialogWindow's content. So in the dialogwindow's loaded event handler, i can get the UserEdit object by using Window.Content, here is the code:

```
public partial class DialogHost : MetroWindow, IDialogWindow
{
    public DialogHost()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public IDialogResult Result { get; set; }

    private void MetroWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var dialogVM = (IDialogViewModel)((UserControl)Content).DataContext;
        dialogVM.CloseDialogWindow += CloseDialogWindow;
    }

    void CloseDialogWindow()
    {
        Close();
    }
}
```

Now,after clicking the cancel button, the dialogwindow will be close.